# Passing arguments from native ios code to javascript (phonegap)

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, cordova

I am trying to pass a value from the `ios plist` file to my `javascript` code like so:

```
NSString *start = @"checkAccountID(";

NSString *AccountID = [[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"AccountID"];

NSString *end = @")";

NSArray *myStrings = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:start, AccountID, end, nil];

NSString *joinedString = [myStrings componentsJoinedByString:@"|"];



[theWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:joinedString];
```

I successfully called a  `test()` `javascript` function from the native code but am having trouble with this one (I am assuming since I am passing an argument). I've also looked into simply saving the value to `HTML5 LocalStorage` from `Objective-C` but am not sure if that is possible. Excuse me if I am doing something silly, I am not an `Objective-C` programmer!

Comment: What is the issue ? The method is not called or the data is not stored ?

Answer (score 0):

If the data that you are passing is of type string, then you will need to have inverted comma before and after the text.
Like

```
checkAccountID('AV231');
```

So, add, inverted comma before and after you write the account ID.

Comment: can you write here what is the accountID for which it is failing?
Does the accountID string also have a inverted comma in it?
That may corrput the Javascript function call